# UserControl Define in Xaml of Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In UserControl tag how can i declare namespace, class name and its inherit class name. if i enter `Namespacename.WindowLevelGraphControl` show an error in `xaml.cs` where i define the class like `WindowLevelGraphControl : UserControl`.
This Error is Class is more define of different base class.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowLevelGraphControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid Height="0" Width="0">

</Grid>
```

If i remove namespace name show error in class like not define intialcomponent();

Waiting for your guidance. Thanks

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Given the language barrier, you should favor expressing yourself in actual C# and XAML, using English sparingly and carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Start By adding as usual a UserControl named WindowLevelGraphControl
This should produce in WindowLevelGraphControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowLevelGraphNS.WindowLevelGraphControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

and in WindowLevelGraphControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class WindowLevelGraphControl : UserControl
```

Now define yout base class in your local namespace i.e. **WindowLevelGraphNS** that inherits **UserControl** but also includes the custom code you want to be available to its children

```
namespace WindowLevelGraphNS
{
    public class BaseClass : UserControl
    {
```

you can then specify that your user control defined above  inherits this class by editing the xaml file like this

```
<local:BaseClass x:Class="WindowLevelGraphNS.WindowLevelGraphControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowLevelGraphNS"
```

and then backend file .xaml.cs like this

```
public partial class WindowLevelGraphControl: BaseClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Got your issue. For example, you have created a class

```
    namespace TestNamespace
    {
        public partial class Test :ModelBase
        {
            public Test()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }

namespace TemplateLoader.Lib.Base
{
    public class ModelBase : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And you are trying to refer this in your xaml.

**Step 1**

You have to add a xml namespace to your xaml using 
xmlns. The xmlns should refer to the base class of the control you are using.
For example, here the base class of the class **Test** is **ModelBase**.

So your xml should contain the reference for the class **ModelBase**.

Add this in your xaml :-

```
xmlns:modelbase="clr-namespace:TemplateLoader.Lib.Base;assembly=TemplateLoader.Lib"
```

This is because the class ModelBase is written the namespace **TemplateLoader.Lib.Base**

**Step 2**

Now that you have added a reference, you can use the class Test in your xaml using the namespace.

```
<modelbase:ModelBase x:Class="TestNamespace.Test"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                     xmlns:modelbase="clr-namespace:TemplateLoader.Lib.Base"
                     mc:Ignorable="d" >
</modelbase:ModelBase>
```

If it does not compile and say partial classes cannot have different declarations. Then you need to recheck the line :-

The x:Class should be the the full name of the class. Here it is TestNamespace.Test Now you should be able to compile your code.